# different score at keras score acc and max probability accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a multi-class classification task on text documents.

I have tried two kind of DL model, CNN and LSTM.

The LSTM model show high acc score(>0.91) at Keras output, but after I calculate the accuracy of the prediction(the max probability of the `model.predict`),
the acc score is about 0.5.

And I test the same thing at the CNN model, but the acc is the same as the Keras output(train acc 0.96, test acc 0.71). So I think there maybe something wrong with my LSTM code.(Its form part of [link](https://www.kaggle.com/jhoward/improved-lstm-baseline-glove-dropout))

Why are they different?

Here is the Keras output and the max probability accuracy of LSTM.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py:112: UserWarning: Converting sparse
IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
"Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
Train on 1039 samples, validate on 116 samples
Epoch 1/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 11s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2707 - acc: 0.9167 - val_loss: 0.2443 - val_acc: 0.9167
Epoch 2/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.2227 - acc: 0.9179 - val_loss: 0.1944 - val_acc: 0.9217
Epoch 3/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1894 - acc: 0.9250 - val_loss: 0.1700 - val_acc: 0.9368
Epoch 4/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1694 - acc: 0.9345 - val_loss: 0.1509 - val_acc: 0.9418
Epoch 5/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1541 - acc: 0.9394 - val_loss: 0.1405 - val_acc: 0.9432
Epoch 6/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1445 - acc: 0.9421 - val_loss: 0.1347 - val_acc: 0.9440
Epoch 7/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 9s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1360 - acc: 0.9439 - val_loss: 0.1240 - val_acc: 0.9533
Epoch 8/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1226 - acc: 0.9520 - val_loss: 0.1200 - val_acc: 0.9555
Epoch 9/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1163 - acc: 0.9541 - val_loss: 0.1164 - val_acc: 0.9511
Epoch 10/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1088 - acc: 0.9584 - val_loss: 0.1135 - val_acc: 0.9526
Epoch 11/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1021 - acc: 0.9609 - val_loss: 0.1070 - val_acc: 0.9612
Epoch 12/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0956 - acc: 0.9633 - val_loss: 0.1061 - val_acc: 0.9562
Epoch 13/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0911 - acc: 0.9650 - val_loss: 0.1100 - val_acc: 0.9533
Epoch 14/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0860 - acc: 0.9680 - val_loss: 0.1003 - val_acc: 0.9641
Epoch 15/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0782 - acc: 0.9716 - val_loss: 0.0965 - val_acc: 0.9634
Epoch 16/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0716 - acc: 0.9732 - val_loss: 0.0957 - val_acc: 0.9655
Epoch 17/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0662 - acc: 0.9752 - val_loss: 0.0984 - val_acc: 0.9648
Epoch 18/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 9s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0644 - acc: 0.9764 - val_loss: 0.0996 - val_acc: 0.9662
Epoch 19/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0614 - acc: 0.9765 - val_loss: 0.0897 - val_acc: 0.9677
Epoch 20/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 9s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0564 - acc: 0.9780 - val_loss: 0.1023 - val_acc: 0.9713
289/289 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step
NN Test score: 0.11336773380421257
NN Test accuracy: 0.959919253022613

Train set evaluation:
1155/1155 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
accuracy: 0.5272727272727272
macro precision: 0.36873557666657714
macro recall: 0.3997861468919986
macro f1: 0.361281520651822
micro precision: 0.5272727272727272
micro recall: 0.5272727272727272
micro f1: 0.5272727272727272
[[ 86  30   9   0   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[ 26  56   1   0  25   0   0   0   0   1   0   0]
[  1   0 151   0   4   3   1   0   0   0   0   6]
[ 29   0   0   0  16   0   0   0   0   0   0   3]
[  9   8   0   0  53   0   0   0   0   0   0  60]
[  0   0  27   0  10  46   0   0   0   1   0   1]
[ 13   1   2   0   0   0 103   0   0   0   0   0]
[ 13  10   3   0   4   0   2   0   0   0   0   0]
[ 17   0  11   0   4   0   0   0   0   6   0   2]
[ 76  12   3   0  17   2   0   0   0   4   0   0]
[ 21   0   1   0   1   0  31   0   0   0   0   0]
[  0   1   2   0  13   0   0   0   0   0   0 110]]
Test set evaluation:
289/289 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step
accuracy: 0.5017301038062284
macro precision: 0.33315831055769135
macro recall: 0.3890209913941563
macro f1: 0.351037197057408
micro precision: 0.5017301038062284
micro recall: 0.5017301038062284
micro f1: 0.5017301038062284
[[20  7  3  0  5  0  0  0  0  2  0  0]
[11 15  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  1 28  0  5  2  1  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 5  1  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  5]
[ 1  3  0  0 18  0  0  0  0  0  0  9]
[ 0  0  5  0  2 12  0  0  0  2  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0 27  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 3  5  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 2  0  2  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[15  3  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 8  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0 25]]
```

And the code

```
def build_model(embedding_weights, maxlen, nb_classes):
    n_embedding_vocab = embedding_weights.shape[0]
    embedding_dim = embedding_weights.shape[1]
    inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
    x = Embedding(n_embedding_vocab, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_weights])(inp)
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(x)
    x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
    x = Dense(50, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
    x = Dense(nb_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def main():
    print('X_train:', X_train.shape, 'Y_train:', Y_train.shape)
    model = build_model(embedding_weight, maxlen, n_class)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1)
    score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
    print('NN Test score:', score[0])
    print('NN Test accuracy:', score[1])

    print('Train set evaluation:')
    pred_probs = model.predict([X_train], batch_size=32, verbose=1)
    model.save(self.lstm.model_path)
    pred = np.argmax(pred_probs, axis=1)

    getEvaluate_SLC(targets[train_idx], pred, label_encoder)

    print('Test set evaluation:')
    pred_probs = model.predict([X_test], batch_size=32, verbose=1)
    model.save(self.lstm.model_path)
    pred = np.argmax(pred_probs, axis=1)

    getEvaluate_SLC(targets[test_idx], pred, label_encoder)
```

Comment: If only one class is correct, you may use 'categorical_accuracy'. Or you can also use the loss as 'categorical_crossentropy'. The problem with binary crossentropy and a regular accuracy is that every zero in the prediction is a correct prediction. Then your accuracy is easily `(nb_classes-1)/nb_classes`.

Comment: I change the code `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])`

Comment: But the performance in Keras still show relative high `Epoch 20/20
1039/1039 [==============================] - 10s 9ms/step - loss: 0.3744 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8768 - val_loss: 0.6451 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.8276`

Comment: The accuracy score is still around 0.5 by the max probability prediction.

Comment: I found I load the old model.
This solve my problem. Thanks for your answer!